# SQL: Validate whether at least 1 record per user is marked as primary

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

I have a table `EmployeeInformation` with these columns:

```
  EmployeeInformationID
  Essentia_ID
  ADP_ID
  SSN
  FirstName
  LastName
  SupervisorOrVP
  LocationNum
  Primary
  EmployeeActive
  RecordActive
  CreatedBy
  CreateDate
  ModifiedBy
  ModifiedDate
```

Each employee can have only one `EmployeeInformationID`, but can have multiple `ADP_ID`s (I inherited this database).

So the `ADP_ID` is unique, but `EmployeeInformationID` is not. However 1 record should be marked as primary.

I need to validate that each employee record has at least one record marked as primary. This will be done inside a frequently used program before I do some calculations and create other records in other tables.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: And what do the values of `Primary` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a query.  The following gets exceptions:

```
select EmployeeInformationID
from EmployeeInformation
group by EmployeeInformationID
having max(Primary) = 0;
```

This assumes `Primary` is a numeric value that takes on values of 0 and 1.  Similar logic can be used if the field has different values.

If you want *exactly* one such record, then:

```
select EmployeeInformationID
from EmployeeInformation
group by EmployeeInformationID
having sum(Primary) = 1;
```

Or:

```
having sum(case when Primary = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Comment: I modified it a little because it is bit 0 or 1: 

select EmployeeInformationID
from EmployeeInformation
group by EmployeeInformationID
having sum(convert(int,Primaryfile)) <> 1

This gave me the list of offending Employee IDS.